# rostopic pub python syntax error

Tags: ros, python, syntax, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I need to use the rostopic pub command in phyton shell script:
In c++ the command is:
rostopic pub -r 5 /uav1/sug_cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[0.0, 0.2, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'

In python I entered like this:
['rostopic', 'pub', '-r 5', '/uav1/sug_cmd_vel', 'geometry_msgs/Twist', '--','['0.0, 0.2,0.0', '0.0,0.0,0.0']'
Also, I tried several other combinations but still getting syntax error.
Can anyone help with this issue?. Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/176677/rostopic-pub-python-syntax-error/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using python why do you want to use the following command?

> rostopic pub -r 5 /uav1/sug_cmd_vel
> geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[0.0, 0.2,
> 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'

This command is meant to be used directly from the command line

You could just use rospy directly

```
import rospy
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('your_package')
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
rospy.init_node('dummy')
# publish to cmd_vel
p = rospy.Publisher('/uav1/sug_cmd_vel', Twist)
# create a twist message, fill in the details
twist = Twist()
twist.linear.x =0.0;                 
twist.linear.y = 0.2; 
twist.linear.z = 0.0;   
twist.angular.x = 0; 
twist.angular.y = 0;  
twist.angular.z = 0; 
p.publish(twist)
```

don't forget to add geometry_msgs as dependency to your package in the manifest.xml.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0